# Qt Render QTablelView For Print Using QPrinter

Tags: c++, qt, printing, qprinter

I am trying to Print an invoice using Qt. One of the features necessary to for an invoice is a table for this I have decided to use a QTabelWidget because I understand how to use them but I am receiving an error stating "no matching member function for call to 'render'". How can I remedy this issue and is it even possible to print a QTableView. My code is below

```
QPrinter Print;
Print.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
Print.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);
Print.setDuplex(QPrinter::DuplexAuto);
QTableWidget PrintTable;
PrintTable.setRowCount(ui->tableWidget_Invoice->rowCount());
PrintTable.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
PrintTable.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
QTableWidgetItem *Product_CODE = new QTableWidgetItem;
QTableWidgetItem *Description = new QTableWidgetItem;
QTableWidgetItem *Unit_Price = new QTableWidgetItem;
QTableWidgetItem *Qty = new QTableWidgetItem;
QTableWidgetItem *Total_Price = new QTableWidgetItem;
for(int x =0; x<ui->tableWidget_Invoice->rowCount(); x++)
{
    Product_CODE->setText(ui->tableWidget_Invoice->item(x, 2)->text());
    Description->setText(ui->tableWidget_Invoice->item(x, 1)->text());
    Unit_Price->setText(ui->tableWidget_Invoice->item(x, 3)->text());
    Qty->setText(ui->tableWidget_Invoice->item(x, 0)->text());
    Total_Price->setText(ui->tableWidget_Invoice->item(x, 4)->text());
    PrintTable.setItem(x, 0, Product_CODE);
    PrintTable.setItem(x, 1, Description);
    PrintTable.setItem(x, 2, Unit_Price);
    PrintTable.setItem(x, 3, Qty);
    PrintTable.setItem(x, 4, Total_Price);
}
QHeaderView* header = PrintTable.horizontalHeader();
header->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
PrintTable.render(Print);
```

Comment: You're trying to call a method that doesn't exist. You must pass the *address* of the paint device to `render()`. The correct statement should read: `PrintTable.render(&Print)`. I'm voting to close this as a typo. I'm not sure if that `render` call will do much on a hidden widget, though.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue.

Comment: how would i make it unhidden so it can be shown for print?

Comment: Have you tried to make sure that it doesn't work? If it doesn't work, then you have to `show()` the widget before you attempt to `render()` it.